# play activator - runtimeException: smtp.host needs to be set in application.conf in order to use this plugin (or set smtp.mock to true)

Tags: exception, playframework, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

I am trying to run play activator template named "playStartApp".
    But, it is giving me following runtime exception:

```
RuntimeException: smtp.host needs to be set in application.conf in order to use this plugin (or set smtp.mock to true)\

    java.lang.RuntimeException: smtp.host needs to be set in application.conf in order to use this plugin (or set smtp.mock to true)
         com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin$$anonfun$4.apply(MailerPlugin.scala:329)
         com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin$$anonfun$4.apply(MailerPlugin.scala:329)
         scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
         com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin.mailerInstance$lzycompute(MailerPlugin.scala:329)
         com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin.mailerInstance(MailerPlugin.scala:326)
         com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin.onStart(MailerPlugin.scala:343)
         play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)`


I tried both:
- set mail.smtp=mock

- mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.user=yourGmailLogin
mail.smtp.pass=yourGmailPassword
mail.smtp.channel=ssl

pls suggest how to resolve this?
```

Answer (score 3):

In the "playStartApp" activator template, you can either -

1. Use a mock mailer, by entering the following in conf/application.conf

   ```
   smtp.mock=true
   ```

The mock option will render email output to the console. If you are using the Activator UI, you'll be able to see the mail output in the logs on the "Run" tab.

2. Mention the SMTP server details in conf/application.conf

   ```
   smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
   smtp.port=587
   smtp.user="user@gmail.com"
   smtp.password="password"
   smtp.ssl=true
   mail.from="PlayStartApp@yourdomain.com"
   mail.sign=The PlayStartApp Team
   ```

You can use gmail servers for sending mails as well, which I have mentioned above.

Alternatively, in the "playStartApp", just rename conf/mail.conf.example to conf/mail.conf and move all your SMTP related configuration here. Please note that conf/mail.conf is mentioned in .gitignore.

Resources (Play Documentation):

[Mail configuration parameters](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/configuration#mail)

[SMTP Configuratoin](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/emails#smtp)

Comment: During testing, if you are using new GlobalSettings, your conf will not be loaded. In that case, pass smtp.mock as Configuration to Global settings:- `HashMap<String, Object> configMap = new HashMap<>();
            configMap.put("smtp.mock", true);
            application = play.test.Helpers.fakeApplication(configMap, new GlobalSettings());`